# JQuery Mobile Parse JSON for ListView

Tags: jquery, json, listview, mobile

This question has been asked lots and have spent the last 3 days going through a number of different 'solutions', none of which I can get to work.

I have a huge JSON file, some 150k entries, that I want to view as a ListVIew in JQuery Mobile. (I will be using the Filter to actually use the data)

The best I have come up with is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>




</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="output">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        //simulating the JSON coming from the server
var json = '["City1","City2","City3"]';
//jQuery getJSON will do this step
var data = $.parseJSON(json);

//and this is your code
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#output').children('ul').append('<p>'+value+'</p>').listview('refresh');
});

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the .listview('refresh') then all three JSON entries are listed in the same ListView field. I obviously want them seperated.

Can anyone advise on how to do this?

With thanks

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) first you need to have the proper [JSON string format](http://www.json.org/)

so I guess your variable

```
var json = '["City1","City2","City3"]';
```

should look more like:

```
var json = '{"city":"City1"},{"city":"City2"},{"city":"City2"}';
```

then before to convert it to JSON, you would rather want to split it first

```
var jsonSplit = json.split(',');
```

and convert to JSON every separated part within an array

```
var data = new Array(), i;
for(i in jsonSplit){
 if(jsonSplit[i].length){ //remove last empty element after .split()
  data[i] = $.parseJSON(jsonSplit[i]);
 }
}
```

then you can manipulate `data` as a javascript object

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `li` elements.

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#output').children('ul').append('<li><p>'+value+'</p></li>').listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#output').children('ul').append('<li><p>'+value+'</p></li>').listview('refresh');
});
```

Remove Listview(refresh) based on what you are doing here you don't need a refresh each time. If you are dynamically adding it through say php... You would need to refresh at the end.

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#output').children('ul').append('<li><p>'+value+'</p></li>');
});
```