# JQuery mobile listview update from json file

Tags: json, html, jquery-mobile

after spending last days trying to find out a solution , now I'm asking help for understanding which is/are the error/s of my code. Starting from the following external Json file `listviewJsonData.json`

```
var itemList = [{"title":"Title_1","description":"Blah blah1"},{"title":"Title_2","description":"Blah blah2"}];
```

I'm updating a listview trough the following code:

```
<div id="dataList">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var serviceURL = "https://.../.../listviewJsonData.json";
            var outputitem = '';
            $.getJSON(serviceURL,function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index,item) {
                        outputitem += '<li><h4>'+ item[index].title +'</h4></li>';
                        $('#dataList').append(outputitem);
                    }
                    $('#dataList').listview('refresh');
            }); 
        </script>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This code doesn't get me any update and the listview remains empty,
I've also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972513/jquery-mobile-parse-json-for-listview) but I was not able to find out a solution to my issue.

Can anyone give me any help?
thnks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your script is in-line and may fire before jQuery Mobile loads or enhances your markup. Try invoking your script by firing it as part of your pageinit event.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  enhanceMyDataList();
});
```

Also, you are appending `<li>` items to a container `<div>`, not your `<ul>`. Move/combine your `id` attribute.

`<ul id="dataList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">`

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but it still doesnt work. 
How can I debug and see if the call $.getJSON assign "data" as "itemList"? At this point I'm not sure if  "data" and "item" used in sequent call $.each(data, function(index,item) are correct. I mean if Json variable "itemList" is parsed and assigned correctly by the script.

Comment: You can use the developer tools in your browser. Set a breakpoint and examine your variables.

Comment: Can you suggest me something free? right now I'm using only smultron as text editor for coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
  <ul id="dataList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var serviceURL = "https://.../.../listviewJsonData.json";
     $.getJSON(serviceURL,function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(index,item) {
         $('#dataList').append('<li><h4>'+ item.title +'</h4></li>');
       });
       $('#dataList').listview('refresh');
     });
  </script>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I changed the div id to ul and a syntax error on script.

Comment: I've tried both the suggested solutions, but it stil doesnt want to collaborate :S.
@andleer - I've also tried both('live', and 'bind')
$('#mainPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) { getDataList(); };

Comment: I was updating the comment for both the solutions. I'm new on this so sorry if I'm posting in the wrong box ;)

Comment: Check the changes that were made.